# Problem with Snap and TOR on boot

Tags: boot, snap, tor

I have been running Kubuntu 22.04 for a couple months and installed the TOR Browser via TOR Browser Launcher about a month ago. My laptop booted up fine until now when I get these errors:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Entropy Daemon based HAVEGE algorithm
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP 
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[FAILED] Failed to start Wait until snapd is fully loaded
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon
[ 3182.765637] elan_i2c i2c-ELAN0000:00: invalid report id data (ff)
```

It never finishes booting.